# [Android Slices]: SliceRow setTitleItem not working

Tags: android, android-slices

I'm trying out the Android Slices and found that there is no way to build the Slice Row with setTitleItem only. I want to create the Slice as like the attached screenshot. But it appears that `setTitleItem` method not working.

**Artifact used** `implementation 'androidx.slice:slice-builders-ktx:1.0.0-alpha4`

```
return list(context, sliceUri, ListBuilder.INFINITY) {
            row {
                setTitleItem(createActivityAction(Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java), R.drawable.ic_pizza_slice_24, SliceHints.ICON_IMAGE))
                title = "Welcome Android Slice"
                subtitle = "It has Start Item"
            }
        }
```

[I've opened a Google Issue but it's not helpful.](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/112472535)

Please let me know if anybody knows what I'm doing wrong here.

**The code is here:**

[Github Code](https://github.com/saurabhkpatel/SampleAndroidSlice/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/saurabh/androidslices/SliceProblemProvider.kt)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the first row of a Slice cannot have a start item. As Slices are still in development this could be subject to change in the future. Using `setTitleItem()` to set a start item in following rows should work:

```
return list(context, sliceUri, ListBuilder.INFINITY) {
    row {
        title = "Welcome Android Slice"
        subtitle = "Header row"
    }
    row {
        setTitleItem(createActivityAction(Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java), R.drawable.ic_pizza_slice_24, SliceHints.ICON_IMAGE))
        title = "2nd row"
        subtitle = "It has Start Item"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an alternative answer. Here is the issue to track: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/112472535

Answer (score 0):

When there is no header, the first-row item automatically becomes header. 
As the header does not have an option for `setTitleItem()`, the icon is not displayed in the left corner.

In your case, the reason for the icon being displayed on the right corner is due to the fact that header's primary action is displayed on the right side

> Take a look at the [appendix of this document](https://blog.novoda.com/android-p-slices-missing-documentation-part-1/) they have mentioned
>   **You can have a header, but if you don't, the first item becomes automatically a header**
>
> Also take a look at this [google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74917014)

In the future, there might be a possibility of support for `setTitleItem()` in the header of android slice.